# Unable to archive in React Native - Archive Fails with duplicate symbols for architecture arm64

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, podfile

It's showing

> 285 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
>
> Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Strangely, I can't seem to get Archive to work in XCode but the build succeeds without the errors on duplicate symbols and it's running properly on simulator as well. I'm getting this error only when I'm trying to make archive.

The project is on React Native 0.56.0, podfile installed as well.

I have no idea what the problem might be.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're coming from an old React Native template and started using `cocoapods`, make sure to remove all libraries linked on `.xcodeproj`:

1. First remove the libraries links:

[image: Links deletion]

2. Then the delete projects references too:

[image]

Finally, try archiving again.

Comment: Paixāo, i'm working in .xcworkspace not in xcodeproj.

Comment: No problem, the changes made on your .xcodeproj reflects on your .xcworkspace as well. But anyway, if you follow the instructions above opening either .xcodeproj or .xcworkspace it should work.

Comment: Paixao,this is not working for me, i deleted all the libraray as it shows and it stopped to build the project.i have many more library then in this picture